# Using Test Configuration when running on-demand automated tests from VSTS Test Hub

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops

My organization has moved from executing automated tests within MTM to executing automated tests within the VSTS Test Hub, via Release Definitions. We're using MSTest to run tests with Selenium / C#.

It is a requirement for us to be able to run any individual test on-demand, post-build, and to use the Test Configuration to control the browser. This was working without an issue when runnings tests through MTM.

Previously, when running tests through MTM, my MSTest TestContext's "Properties" were populated with runtime parameters, such as the Test Configuration, such as `TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestConfigurationName__"]`. The runtime properties could also be seen in the resulting .trx file.

Now, when running tests through the VSTS Test Hub, those values are no longer set in TestContext automatically, nor do I see them in the .trx file, or in my Release deployment logs.

Are there any suggestions as to how the Test Configuration values of each test can be propagated into TestContext (or accessible via code otherwise) to be able to control the browser at test run-time?

- I have considered creating a .runsettings file, but am unaware as to how Test Configuration variables would be dynamically populated into that file.
- I have considered attempting to query the Test Run / Test Results in my Selenium code to determine the Test Points / Configuration, but am unaware of how to determine the Test Run ID (I see the Test Run ID in the release logs, but don't know how to programmatically access it)
- I have seen a VSTS Extension called 'VSTS Test Extensions' which is purported to inject the VSTS variables into a .runsettings file, but there are no details as to how to configure the .runsettings file in order to accomplish this, and the old MTM-style parameter names do not seem to work.
- Are Test Configuration variables accessible globally in VSTS somehow? 
  I.e. could I create a PowerShell Release task to somehow access test run / test point data? Microsoft does not provide any indication about how to use Test Configurations other than using them for manual tests.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't get them from TestContext and runsettings file can't set variables dynamically during the testing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more review, it seems that my only option is a giant hack:

I noticed that in the Release logs, the [TEST_RUNID] is output, which points me to the $(test.runid) variable, which I didn't know existed.

I can output the Run ID to an external file via a Powershell Release task.

I can then have my test code read that file, perform an API call to VSTS querying the Test Results for that Run ID, and then use that response to output the Test Configuration Name for each Test Case ID.

I can then match up my Test Case ID within each of my test methods with the Test Case IDs from the service call response, and set the browser according to the Test Configuration Name.

The only issue then is if the same test exists multiple times in the same run with different configurations, which can be hacked around by querying the Test Run every time a test begins and checking which configuration has already been run based on the State ("Pending", etc.) or by some other means I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Have you since figured out any alternative methods to find TestRunID?

Comment: Nope; that method worked fairly well though, for all its hackiness. I've since left that project and no longer use VSTS so I'm not sure if there's a better alternative now.