# How to get current Run Id of automated test in TFS 2017

Tags: c#, tfs, mstest

Previously I would use:

```
TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestRunId__"]
```

to get the current Id of the run that is executing a specific test case. But in 2017 that doesn't seem to be the case as it is returning an invalid number.

By using the following code I was able to dump the keys of TestContext and it looks like that parameter is no longer present..

```
private static IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> SafeCast(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
    {
        yield return entry;
    }
}
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var dictionaryEntries = SafeCast(TestContext.Properties).Select(_ => new { Key = _.Key.ToString(), _.Value }).ToArray();

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("dump.txt"))
{
     foreach (var entry in dictionaryEntries)
     {
         file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
         var outputString = string.Format("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
         Trace.WriteLine(outputString);
      }
}
```

These are the current keys:

```
ResultsDirectory
AgentId
AgentName
TestRunDirectory 
ControllerName 
DataCollectionEnvironmentContext 
TestResultsDirectory 
TestLogsDir 
TestDeploymentDir 
TestRunResultsDirectory 
TestDir 
AgentLoadDistributor 
DeploymentDirectory 
TotalAgents 
TotalAgents 
FullyQualifiedTestClassName 
TestName
```

Is there a way that I can force the Run Id to be passed through the TestContext or any other ways I can get the current Run Id?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get test run id in test method as running test through MTM when run tests during the build (Functional test).

The Workaround is that you can specify the value in runsettings and get the value during test.

More information, you can refer to [Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/)

Similar case: [How to retrieve a Test Case ID that is currently running through TFS (vNext) build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843920/how-to-retrieve-a-test-case-id-that-is-currently-running-through-tfs-vnext-bui)

Comment: Where can I find the string literals of the values that I'm supposed to specify in the release definition? Right now I'm attempting to use `$(test.TestCaseId)` and `$(test.RunId)`. RunId is working, but TestCaseId is not...

Comment: No such list, but you can check the solution in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005625/using-test-configuration-when-running-on-demand-automated-tests-from-vsts-test-h

Comment: No it seems unacceptable to me that the suggested action is to supply parameters to the test run that there is no documentation for. Especially when this was a feature that worked on the previous iterations of TFS.

Comment: You could open a user voice at website below: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145257-dashboards-and-reporting